# Windows Phone 8: How to add the bottom menu to a nokia map control?

Tags: maps, windows-phone-8, here-api

As you can see in this screenshot: http://cdn.conversations.nokia.com.s3.amazonaws.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/wp_ss_20120831_0006-614x1024.jpg, there is an expandable menu with search, places and my places. How is this menu called? I need to find some info about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the [Application Bar.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431813%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

See: [How to create an app bar using XAML for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394040%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It's called Application Bar. You can learn more (and see examples) about it [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Application_Bar_for_Windows_Phone).